# Summable sequence whose ratio satisfies a certain condition

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, analysis

I am interested in constructing a positive sequences $(a_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ such that
$$
\sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}} a_n < \infty \quad (1) ,\quad \sup_{ n \in \mathbb{N} } \frac{a_n}{a_{n+1}} < \infty \quad (2), \quad \sup_{ n \in \mathbb{N} } \frac{a_n}{a_{n-1}} = \infty \quad(3).
$$
The sequence $2^{-n}$ satisfies $(1)$ and $(2)$, but not $(3)$. The sequence $2^{n^2}$ satisfies $(2)$ and $(3)$, since
$$
\frac{a_n}{a_{n+1}} = \frac{1}{2^{2n+1}}, \quad \frac{a_n}{a_{n-1}} = 2^{2n-1},
$$
but not $(1)$. The sequence $2^{-(n^2)}$ satisfies $(1)$, with $(2)$ being infinite and $(3)$ being finite. What would be an example of a sequence satisfying all the three consitions?

Comment: @user376343 Can you clarify why? It does not seem to follow directly from the ratio test.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming $a_n \neq 0$ for all $n$ condition $(1)$ and $(3)$ can never both be true. To see that, note that condition $(3)$ implies that $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_{n}} > 1$ and thus by the ratio-test (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratio_test)) the series diverges.

Edit: Maybe this was impecise, so to clarify: (3) implies the existence of a supsequence $a'_n$ s.t. $\lim _{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac{a'_{n+1}}{a'_n} > 1$. And thus by the ratio test $\sum_{n = 0}^\infty a'_n = \infty$. And since $a_n>0~ \forall n$ as you stated we also have $\sum_{n = 0}^\infty a_n = \infty$

Comment: But one would need to check that $\liminf_{ n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} > 1$. From $(3)$ it follows that $\limsup_{ n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} = \infty$.

Comment: I hope the edit clarifies this